# I can't fix the accents

Tags: python

I am having problems with a code created in python, and it is that when I generate some texts in json the accents are not appreciated

This is my code that I am using...

```
import requests

url =  requests.get(f"https://images.habbo.com/habbo-web-news/es/production/front.json")
resumen =  url.json()[0]['summary']

print(resumen)
```

I get these weird characters "& # x E D;"

Comment: It is because the site you are requesting that information from has those weird characters.

Comment: The characters that you see are the result of an HTML encoding. I decoded the summary below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this helps:

```py
import html
import requests

url = requests.get(
    f"https://images.habbo.com/habbo-web-news/es/production/front.json")

content = url.json()

summary = content[0]["summary"]

decoded = html.unescape(summary)

print (decoded)
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe it has to do with the encoding, please refer to [the request documentation in the response content section](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart/#response-content). The "content" key on the json files have a strange format to be spanish, tho.